# mismatched types expected `i8`, found `()`

Tags: rust

I am trying to make a temperature converter in Rust, but for some reason my code here gives me an error. I am trying to convert the choice `String` to an `i8` type.

```rust
use std::io;

fn main() {
    println!("Welcome! Would you like to convert from (1) Fahrenheit to Celsius, or (2) from Celsius to Fahrenheit?");
    let mut choice = String::new();

    io::stdin()
        .read_line(&mut choice)
        .expect("Failed to read line");

    println!("{}", choice);

    let choice: i8 = match choice.trim().parse() {
        Ok(num) => num,
        Err(_) => {
            println!("Invalid input, please input a number.");
        }
    };
}

fn convert_to_c(f_temp: f64) {
    let mut c_temp: f64;
    c_temp = f_temp - 32.0 * 0.5556;
    println!("{}F in Celsius is: {}", f_temp, c_temp);
}

fn convert_to_f(c_temp: f64) {
    let mut f_temp: f64;
    f_temp = c_temp * 1.8 + 32.0;
    println!("{}C in Fahrenheit is: {}", c_temp, f_temp);
}
```

```
error[E0308]: mismatched types
  --> src/main.rs:15:19
   |
15 |           Err(_) => {
   |  ___________________^
16 | |             println!("Invalid input, please input a number.");
17 | |         }
   | |_________^ expected `i8`, found `()`
```

Comment: If the input cannot be parsed as an `i8`, you print an error message, but then what value should `choice` take? You can fix the issue by replacing `println` with `panic`, which will cause the program to abort and avoid the need for a value for `choice`.

Comment: @Jmb I want to display "Please enter a number from 1-2" (if it isn't), should I use something other than a match expression for something like this?

Comment: You want to display a message **and then what?** If you want to ask again until the user gets it right, you'll need a loop of some kind. If you just want the program to panic on bad input, use `panic!`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your match arms both need to return the same type. Since you want to request new input from the user, there's no need to handle the `Err` case here, just `loop` until a correct value is entered.

This snippet loops until the value `input` can be parsed without issues. In that case `if let Some(v) ..` it breaks with the value parsed. If the value cannot be parsed, it just loops along and tries again.

```
let mut input = String::new();
let choice: u8 = loop {
    io::stdin()
        .read_line(&mut input)
        .expect("Failed to read line");

    println!("{}", input);

    if let Some(v) = input.trim().parse().ok() {
        break v;
    }
    input.clear();
    println!("Invalid input. Please input a number.");
};
```

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that this match statement is an expression that has to return an `i8` to assign to `choice`, but the `Err` arm doesn't return an `i8`.

```rust
    let choice: i8 = match choice.trim().parse() {
        Ok(num) => num,
        Err(_) => {
            println!("Invalid input, please input a number.");
        }
    };
```

One way to get it to run, is to have the Err branch panic so it never returns at all.

```rust
        Err(_) => {
            println!("Invalid input, please input a number.");
            panic!();
        }
```